# How do I plot in matplotlib a Pandas DataSeries with index Date?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following Pandas DataSeries:

```
Date
2006-01    16.050000
2006-02    14.052632
2006-03    15.565217
             ...    
2019-11    31.650000
2019-12    20.350000
Freq: M, Name: Value, Length: 168, dtype: float64

print(type(data_month2))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(data_month2.index))
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.period.PeriodIndex'>
```

I want to display the series values in Matplotlib, I have tried this:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.plot(data_month2.index, data_month2);
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

Comment: You could have asked me this in a follow up to my post. This is a simple plot call: `data_month2.plot.line(); plt.show()`

Comment: Being a matplotlib I preferred to make a separate question. Thanks a lot for the answer, feel free to add it as answer. For you it might be easy, but it is not for many others.

Comment: No worries, I think this has been asked before as well. I will mark as duplicate but happy to have helped.